# Better method to close a view when dragging top of a tableview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my UITableViewController I have setup a top drag, but I'm using a Count process to decide when to close the view, that way the user does not close the view on accident by scrolling to the top of the tableview, however this creates another issues where the user opens the view and decides to close the view, so they have to double drag to escape. There has to be a better option?

```
//detect dragging
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    float scrollOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    NSLog(@"%f",scrollOffset);

    if (scrollOffset < 0)
    {
        if(!self.dragCount) self.dragCount = 0;
        self.dragCount++;
        // then we are at the top
        if(self.dragCount == 2) [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];
    }
}
```

Comment: close the view or close the view controller ? do u have tableview in uiview controller ? what r u trying to dismiss ?

Comment: I'm closing the view controller, e.g. dismissViewControllerAnimated.. is there a long drag or something like that I can use to tell that the user is pulling down on the tableview. I like the swipe down method, but as far as I know I can't use that because the user is using a tableview which uses the swipe method to move up and down.

Comment: if it is the table view, u can use scrollview did scroll, and based on content offset.y, you can choose how much amount of scroll needed to dismiss the view

Comment: Thank you!

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    float scrollOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    NSLog(@"%f",scrollOffset);
    if(scrollOffset <= -140) [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];
}

Comment: Yeah, worked nicely!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is the table view, you can use `scrollViewDidScroll:`, and based on `contentOffset.y`, you can choose the amount of scroll needed to dismiss the view.

Answer (score 1):

The end result from Mr. T's comment above:

```
   //detect dragging
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    float scrollOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    NSLog(@"%f",scrollOffset);
    if(scrollOffset <= -140) [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];
}
```